# Lodash: Remove consecutive duplicates from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I need to reduce this array of objects

```
[
  {id:1, value:'A'},
  {id:2, value:'B'},
  {id:3, value:'B'},
  {id:4, value:'B'},
  {id:5, value:'A'},
  {id:6, value:'A'},
  {id:7, value:'B'}
]
```

to

```
[
  {id:1, value:'A'},
  {id:2, value:'B'},
  {id:5, value:'A'},
  {id:7, value:'B'}
]
```

If consecutive objects have the same value, it keeps the first one and removes the rest.

My current solution is

```
var lastValue = undefined;
var result = [];
var propPath = 'value'; // I need later to reference nested props

objects.filter(function(object){
  var value = _.at(object, propPath);
  if (!_.isEqual(value, lastValue)){
    result.push(object);
    lastValue = value;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

My questions is, as Lodash has a lot of features, is there a **Lodash way** of doing this more simply? Maybe some pre-built solution without using helper variables (lastValue and result).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved with [`.reject`](https://lodash.com/docs#reject):

```
_.reject(objects, function (object, i) {
    return i > 0 && objects[i - 1].value === object.value;
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fjohxhkg)**</kbd>

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but the lodash [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#reject) says nothing about the second argument (index) of the predicate. Is the document outdated or is this something unofficial, internal, or subject to change?

Comment: All the methods to manipulate collections have a predicate with three arguments: `(value, index|key, collection)`. I guess it's just missing in `_.reject` documentation but the other ones have this detail (`_.filter`, `_.map`, `_.forEach`, `_.every`, `_.some`, etc). For info, the third argument `collection` is useful in some case, e.g. `_.filter(_.sortBy(items, 'id'), function (item, i, sortedItems) { … }`.